# Why is the result of this Linux command not being piped?

Tags: linux, terminal

I am learning to use the Linux terminal and it seems piping doesn't work as I would expect and I want to understand why.

I have two files:

File1

```
John   1
Paul   2
Peter  3
Henry  5
```

File2

```
John    2
Peter   7
Francis 5
```

My idea was to order File2 and then join the ordered result with File1 by using the following command:

```
sort -k2n File2 | join -1 2 -2 2 File1 File2
```

I expected as a result

```
2 John Paul 
5 Francis Henry
```

but instead it seems it does not order it prior to piping and returns:

```
2 John Paul
join: File2:3: is not ordered: Francis 5
```

why is it not piping my sorting??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sort file2` does nothing to file2, it writes the sorted content to standard output (which I suppose you expect, since you're using a pipeline).

`join file1 file2` ignores standard input (i.e., the pipe) and operates on data from the files specified.  In particular, file2 is not sorted.

You probably wanted to code `-` instead of `file2` in the join command.  `-` means read from standard input.

Answer (score 0):

The sort command is not reading from the standard input, so your sorting of File2 is not taken into account by the join.

Your solution should look like:

```
$ sort -k2n File2 | join -1 2 -2 2 File1 -

2 Paul John
5 Henry Francis
```